# D3 Force simulation based on force link weight – how to avoid nodes overlapping?

Tags: d3.js, graph

I do D3 ("d3": "^7.0.0",) Force simulation that's informativity is based on nodes grouping which groups depend on the weight of links between each node.

`d3.forceLink(links).strength((link) => link.weight)` do exectly the right thing but i want avoid nodes overlapping to keep them clickable.

I expected `.force('collide', d3.forceCollide((n) => node radius + some padding))` will prevent overlapping but in vain.
Could you help me to understand how to make forceCollide and forceLink respect each other?

// Nodes.ts

```
export const DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE = 10;

class Nodes {
    ...
    nodeSize = DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE;
    selection: NodesSelection;

    constructor(initArgs: NodesInitArgs) {
        ...
        this.selection = this.init(initArgs.nodesData);
        ...
    }
    
    init = (data: SNANode[]) => {
        const nodesSelection = d3
          .select('.force-graph-container svg')
          .append('g')
          .attr('id', 'nodes-and-links')
          .attr('stroke-width', 1)
          .selectAll('circle')
          .data(data)
          .join('circle')
          .classed('circle', true)
          .attr('id', (n) => n.id)
          ... other attributes ... 
          .attr('r', (n) => this.nodeSize * n.radiusMultiplier) // <---- DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE * pre counted number in the range [1.0 - 4.0] that has been saved to each node.

          ... other attributes ... ;
    
        return nodesSelection;
      };
```

//Simulation.ts

```
const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      /*
        I expected that collide radius should totally prevent overlapping
        if it equals to the particular node radius + some padding,
        so i put there DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE * n.radiusMultiplier + padding 2.
        Did i get the forceCollide idea correct?
      */
      .force(
        'collide',
        d3.forceCollide((n) => DEFAULT_NODE_SIZE * n.radiusMultiplier + 2),
      )
      /*
        Increasing the charge strength is not a variant
        because it breaks the chart informativity.
      */
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-2000))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(height / 2, width / 2))
      .force('x', d3.forceX())
      .force('y', d3.forceY())

      /*
        The problem goes here. The informativity of this force graph is based on
        link weight. We expect nodes to push or pull each other due to link strength.
        And the chart does it properly due to `.strength((l) => l.weight)`,
        but nodes are heavily overlapping each other
      */
      .force(
        'link',
        d3
          .forceLink(links)
          .id((n) => (n as SNANode).id)
          /*
            while collide force has been totally ignored by the chart
            the distance property does impact. Could you help me to count the distance
            to avoid overlapping?
            
            But to me, it feels semantically wrong because links distances are counted
            based on link weight correctly but just ignore the forceCollide.
            Do i understand d3.forceCollide correct – it had to avoid nodes overlapping?
          */
          //.distance((l) => 500) <-- don't understand how to count, and whether manipulating the distance is the right way at all
          .strength((l) => l.weight),
      );

    simulation.on('tick', handleTick);
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying an iteration count higher than 1? eg, `d3.forceCollide(...).iterations(4);` ?

Comment: Yes, but never tried to increase significantly more than 2, like up to 20. And I did it, also increased the strength to 1, and add 5 to the radius value – that gave me an acceptable result!

So if you put that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.
Thank you, Andrew!